Can the measurability assumption in Fubini's Theorem be relaxed?
If $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that the iterated integrals $\int_X \int_Y f(x, y) d \nu(y) d \mu(x)$ and $\int_Y \int_X f(x, y) d \mu(x) d \nu(y)$ are both well-defined and finite ($f$ is not necessarily measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$), is it possible to assert that these integrals are equal?

Here's a counterexample: Let both $X$ and $Y$ be $\omega_1$, i.e., an uncountable well-ordered set in which each element has only countably many predecessors. Call the ordering $\leq$. Let the $\sigma$-algebra (on both $X$ and $Y$) be the algebra consisting of the countable subsets and the co-countable (i.e., complements of countable) subsets, and let the measure (on both $X$ and $Y$) send the countable sdets to $0$ and the co-countable sets to $1$. Let $f$ be the characteristic function of $\leq$, i.e., $f(x,y)$ is $1$ if $x\leq y$ and $0$ if $y<x$.  Then $\int_X\int_Yf(x,y)\,d\nu(y)\,d\mu(x)=\int_X1\,d\mu(x)=1$ while
$\int_Y\int_Xf(x,y)\,d\mu(x)\,d\nu(y)=\int_Y0\,d\nu(y)=0$.
